# How to kill mysql with moving pid

Tags: macos, mysql, process, launchctl

I have multiple mysql instances running on OSX 10.10. `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld stop` spits out a bunch of warnings and errors, I'm not sure if they're worth sharing. Here's the first error `16164 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.` Running mysql_upgrade fails.

Running `ps aux | grep mysql` results in:

```
clayton         16179   0.0  0.0  2423356    228 s000  R+   10:58AM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn mysql
_mysql          15599   0.0  0.3  3070756  24508   ??  S    10:22AM   0:01.64 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/Beast.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/Beast.local.pid
root            15514   0.0  0.0  2452828    876   ??  Ss   10:22AM   0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql
```

I tried kill the processes `sudo kill -15 16179 15599 15514`, but my user process pid changes. `kill: 16179: No such process`. If I do `ps aux | grep mysql` repeatedly the pid of the first process, owned by clayton, jumps up by 10 each time.

So, next I tried to unload mysql using `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` and `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist` result in `Could not find specified service`.

Ugh. I'm definitely stumped and not sure how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process probably is probably respawning each time when you try to kill it.

You can always try to use `pgrep` and kill them at one go, e.g.:

```
kill $(pgrep mysql)
```

But I think the solution would be to find the source where it's get restarted each time, so try checking list of your running/system daemons by using [`launchctl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html):

```
sudo launchctl list
```

Then unload as described in: [How do you stop MySQL on a Mac OS install?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100948/55075)

If you've the problem with:

> [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table.

probably you're running it wrong, by not specifying the right mysql data directories.  So maybe it's worth to load them again via `launchctl`, check how they were run before, or locate your configuration file and double check the configuration, or you've the [wrong permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21470193/55075) set-up.

Here is sample syntax how you can run it manually:

```
mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --basedir=/var/db/mysql --datadir=/var/db/mysql --plugin-dir=/var/db/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --tmpdir=/tmp/mysql/tmpdir --log-error=/var/log/mysql_error_log.err --pid-file=/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

When using MAMP, the command-line parameters looks like:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf --basedir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --datadir=/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql --plugin-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/plugin --user=mysql --tmpdir=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/tmpdir --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

Answer (score 0):

That first line you're seeing is the  `ps aux | grep mysql` command that you're (re-)running each time, so not one to worry about.

You should be able to kill the mysql process by name if you use `sudo pkill mysql`.